# Clientcontext for FBA in provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, provider-hosted-app

I am using `Forms Based authentication` in provider hosted app.

Once FBA user is logged in SharePoint site, I need to get the `clientcontext` in my app web  (`which is an MVC application`) to check if the user is authenticated so that I can bypass the authentication at the app web level.

Answer (score 0):

This initial set up to configure the trust and authentication between SharePoint and Provider MVC web application would require your patience. I would highly recommend to go through below blogs:

[Using SharePoint Apps with SAML and FBA Sites in SharePoint 2013](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/using-sharepoint-apps-with-saml-and-fba-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/)

I followed the below blog by Wictor Wilen to set up MVC App with SAML claim(**Highly recommended** !).

[SharePoint 2013 with SAML Claims and Provider Hosted Apps](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-with-saml-claims-and-provider-hosted-apps)

Good luck !